# No output string when using zframe_strdup

Tags: zeromq

I am wanting to create a hash table which stores the sender's identity as the key. In order to perform some preliminary checks, I added the following lines to some existing code:

```
zframe_print(sender,"Sender frame print:");
char *string = zframe_strdup(sender);
zclock_log("Sender frame string:%s", string);

Output:
Sender frame print:[005] 006B8B4571
Sender frame string:
```

I don't understand why there is no output when using **zframe_strdup**. Any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why there is no output when using zframe_strdup.

The zframe_print output tells you everything you need.  Your frame is 5 bytes long and contains the bytes 00 6B 8B 45 71.

The zframe_strdup is useful if the frame content is printable text, but that's not the case here.  The identity frame is 5 bytes with no text meaning.  I recommend you simply remove lines 2 and 3 from your code.

When you attempt to print the binary data in the zclock_log statement, it expects the %s string argument to be a null terminated string.  Coincidently, by convention, the first byte of a zeromq generated identity frame is always 0.  Since the first byte is zero, zclock_log  interprets this first byte as the end of the string and you get no output.

[update]

> I am wanting to create a hash table which stores the sender's identity as the key

I think you are on the right track using zframe_strhex.  A hex encoded string will make a nice key for your table.  Yes you eventually have to convert back to binary, but that is a well defined problem you can unit test, and there are plenty of questions/answers right here in StackOverflow about this topic.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information! Just using zframe_print does not suffice, because I need to store the frame content in a char*. Then, I can use the sender identities as keys using the zhash class. I tried zframe_strhex to obtain a hex representation of the sender identity, but then I also need a way to convert the hex representation back to the original identity. Any ideas?